# Разработка без backend. Отключение mock-данных для production

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Для целей разработки без зависимости от backend подключен angular-mock.
Прошу поделится опытом подключения\отключения `angular-mock` в зависимости от production или development.
Сборщик - webpack. Но готов рассмотреть любые идеи и предложения.

UPD.
Преположим, что при сборке проекта мы передали `process.env.NODE_ENV` из nodejs в код нашего приложения. Например,  с помощью такого кода:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  plugins:[
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV
      }
    }),
    // [...]
  ]
  //...
}
```

Остается вопрос, как исключить достаточно объемные файлы с mock-данными из финального bandle (мы ведь все боремся за снижение размеров нашего приложения).
И если "переключить" источник данных для запросов к backend получается (спасибо @AlexandrTovmach). То уменьшить размер финального bandle пока нет.

```js
angular.module('userModule', ['userModuleMock'])
  .factory('userService', userService);

userService.$inject = ['$http'];

function userService($http) {
  return {
    getAll: function() {
      return $http.get('/api/v1/users');
    }
  };
}

angular.module('userModuleMock', ['ngMockE2E'])
  .run(userServiceMock);

userServiceMock.$inject = ['$httpBackend'];

function userServiceMock($httpMock) {
    var users = [
      {
        name: 'John'
      },
      {
        name: 'Mary'
      }
    ];
    $httpMock.whenGET('/api/v1/users').respond(users);
}

angular.module('app', ['userModule'])
  .controller('appController', appController);

appController.$inject = ['userService'];

function appController(userService) {
  userService.getAll()
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      throw err;
    });
}

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'),
  ['app']
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-mocks@1.7.6/angular-mocks.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div ng-controller="appController"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `process.env.NODE_ENV` пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте переменную окружения `process.env.NODE_ENV`.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  // init your angular-mock
}
```

Comment: спасибо за проявленный интерес и предложение. Более подробно возникшие вопросы написал в UPD к вопросу. А если коротко, как можно исключить mock-данные из собираемого приложения?

Comment: Посмотрел апдейт. Во-первых не уверен что Вам нужно прописывать `NODE_ENV` руками, так как эта переменная устанавливается автоматически. Во-вторых я не особо эксперт в angularjs, поэтому не уверен что могу подсказать Best Practice решение, но почему бы не обернуть код импорта и инициации модуля с mock-данными в if...else приведенный в ответе?